# Using JavaScript reset removes format of phone field

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net-mvc

I have 4 input fields for telephone numbers. They all have the [Phone] attribute in the model and the type="tel" in the HTML.

The fields look like this (904) 888-1234 when the form loads.

In model:

```
[Phone]
public string Phone {get;set;}
```

in HTML

```
<input type="tel" value="9048881234">
<button type="reset">reset</button>
```

When the user clicks the reset button, the formatting disappears (9048881234) and the form fails validation on submit.

Is there a way to reset the field so that it restores the format to (904) 888-1234?

Thanks,

Comment: It looks better to have some code.

Answer (score 0):

Solution:

Before reset I store the field's value:

```
let phone = $("#Phone").val()
```

then clear it

```
$("#Phone").val("");
```

Then, after reset, I restore the value if it was not empty.

```
it (phone != ""){
    $("#Phone").val(phone);
}
```